# How do I output everything my program prints to a file?

Tags: c#, output

The thing is, I have made a code to generate giant pyramids of stars. Now I would like to input everything what is written in the console into a text file.
Thanks.

My current code.

```
using System;

namespace Pyramidi
{
class Ohjelma
{
    static void Main()
    {
        int maxHeight = 0;
        do
        {

            Console.Write("Anna korkeus: ");
            maxHeight = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            if (maxHeight > 0)
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                continue;
            }
        }
        while (true);

        for (int height = 0; height < maxHeight; height++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < (maxHeight - height - 1); i++)
            {
                Console.Write(" ");
            }
            for (int i = 1; i <= (height * 2 + 1); i++)
            {
                Console.Write("*");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Like `myProgram.exe > someFile.txt` OR you want change your code to write to file OR you want [tee](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tee_%28Unix%29) equivalent for Windows OR something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest thing to do, and which doesn't require changing your program at all, is to redirect your program's output to a file when you run it:

```
MyProject.exe > file.txt
```

">" is a "redirection operator", as it is in many Unix shells.

If you're on Windows, you can read more about the output redirection operator and other such operators [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx). If you're using a Unix shell, use your shell's redirection operators (e.g., [here's the Bash manual's advice](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html)).

Comment: How do you exactly do this?

Comment: @Tatu: When you run your program at the command line, just add "... > file.txt" after it, exactly as indicated in the answer.

Comment: +1. Start -> Run -> "cmd"... `cd /d`  to folder with your executable... type progame name with redirect  to file...

Comment: +1 This is what I would actually do instead of my answer. Shell commands FTW

Answer (score 3):

John's answer is the fastest and easiest, but StreamWriter is also a solution. This is something that you will use often when you need to write to a file.

I would suggest reading up about [StreamWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.io.streamwriter). This allows you to do output to a file.

You just need to add a StreamWriter object in and replace the Console.WriteLines with the StreamWriter variable name.

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("fileName.txt"))
{
    for (int height = 0; height < maxHeight; height++)
    {                   
        for (int i = 0; i < (maxHeight - height - 1); i++)
        {
            sw.Write(" ");
        }
        for (int i = 1; i <= (height * 2 + 1); i++)
        {
            sw.Write("*");
        }
        sw.WriteLine();
    }
    sw.Flush();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution using [`Console.SetOut`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.setout%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method:

```
using (var writer = new StreamWriter("filepath"))
{
   Console.SetOut(writer);
   do
   {
       Console.Write("Anna korkeus: ");
       maxHeight = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

       if (maxHeight > 0)  break;
       else continue;
  }
  while (true);

  for (int height = 0; height < maxHeight; height++)
  {
       for (int i = 0; i < (maxHeight - height - 1); i++)
       {
           Console.Write(" ");
       }
       for (int i = 1; i <= (height * 2 + 1); i++)
       {
            Console.Write("*");
       }
       Console.WriteLine();
  }
  writer.Flush();
}
```

`Console.SetOut` changes the output stream of the `Console`.So when you use `Console.Write` it writes to that stream instead of `Console`.And then you call `Flush` method which is writes all the data in the underlying stream and clears the buffer.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of writing to the Console, write directly to the file using IO

```
using System;
using System.IO;

class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string path = @"c:\temp\MyTest.txt";
        if (!File.Exists(path))
        {
            // Create a file to write to. 
            using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path))
            {
                sw.WriteLine("Hello");
                sw.WriteLine("And");
                sw.WriteLine("Welcome");
            }
        }

        // Open the file to read from. 
        using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(path))
        {
            string s = "";
            while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(s);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For more information, visit this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.aspx

Comment: The question was for C#

Comment: this question is not about `VB`.

Comment: If you are going to copy and paste, at least copy and paste from the correct language :)

Comment: I was wondering that too, thanks for the quick suggestion though. Sadly wrong language. :D

Comment: Sorry, I have VB as my default on MSDN. :P